# laravel validation does not function as expected

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I'm trying to create a RESTful API using Laravel 10,

when trying to validate the inputs, validation does not work as expected and I get database error for the unique field (obviously when I try to add the value which already exists in db) instead of the proper response provided by the validation process.

here's `routes/api.php` file:

```
Route::controller(AuthController::class)->group(function () {
    Route::post('register', 'register');
});
```

here's the `app/Controller/AuthController.php` file:

```
public function register(RegisterRequest $request) {
    /**
     * some code to register the user
     */
    $user = new User;
    $user->mobile_no = request('mobile')
}
```

here's the `app/Requests/RegisterRequest.php` file:

```
public function rules(): array
{
    return [
        'mobile'=>'required|unique:users,mobile_no|ir_mobile:zero',
    ];
}

public function messages() {
    return [
        'mobile.unique' => 'a custom msg here',
    ];
}

public function failedValidation(Validator $validator)
{
    // the following function exists in `app/helpers.php` and works currectly
    throwBadRequestError([
        'errors' => $validator->errors(),
        'request' => $_REQUEST
    ]);
}
```

here's a screenshot of postman:
[image: here's the unexpected error: 500 Internal Server Error]

why does not the validation throw an error instead of database?

many thanks in advance.

Comment: how you are calling the register api call ? from postman ?

Comment: @DhavalPurohit yes

Comment: okay I mean what is the URL that you hitting?

Comment: 127.0.0.1:8000/api/register

Comment: Do not post pictures of text, they are not helpful. Copy and paste. Have you tried getting rid of the `failedValidation()` method?

Comment: @miken32 I'll keep it mind for the next time, tnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From SQL error message the column you are updating is `users.mobile` while you are testing `users.mobile_no` in the validation

Comment: I think you can add a third parameter to pass validation updating the same record
`'mobile' => 'unique:users,mobile,' . $user->id` or 
`Rule::unique('users','mobile' )->ignore($user->id)`

Comment: That's not the case I've updated the controller plz take a look, but I matched the table column and the request key to make sure and the error is still the same! ‍♂️

Comment: user is not registered yet! I'm stuck at validation error handling by this ridiculous problem.

Comment: The SQL error message still reports (..., mobile, ...)

Comment: Yeah you're right, got confused and didn't run the the migrate:fresh after I changed it, tnx a lot

Comment: four eyes are better than two ;-)